# JetBrains dotTrace: confusing `await` time for async function calls

Tags: c#, async-await, profiling, jetbrains-ide, dottrace

While profiling the app which is using `async/await` functionality with dotTrace I noticed that there is some inconsistency in `await` time for parent and children methods. Let's consider this example:

```
static async Task Main()
{
    await ChildMethod();
}

static async Task ChildMethod()
{
    await SomeOperationAsync();
}
```

The interesting thing is that `await` time of `Main` method might be (or even **will** be) **less than** the `await` time of the `ChildMethod` which looks strange to me, because intuitively `await` time of parent should be **at least** as `await` time of child.

For real numbers let's go back to the previous example and assume that `SomeOperationAsync` is `Task.Delay(n)`. So the `await` time of the parent will be `x` (`x` is `~n` for the app targeting .NET 6.0 and `<n` for the app targeting .NET Core 3.1) and the `await` time of child will be `~2*x`.

This is the screenshot from dotTrace to get an idea how it looks (for the app targeting .NET Core 3.1 and for `Task.Delay(800)`):

[image]

1. This is `await` time of the method `Main`. **567ms** for `await ChildMethod()`, I expect this to be `~800`, because
   `ChildMethod` awaits `Task.Delay(800)`
2. This is `await` time of the method `ChildMethod`. **1140ms** for `await Task.Delay(800)`. I also expect this to be `~800`.

Probably I misunderstand what `await` time in dotTrace is, so please correct me if so. I understand it as **the time needed to schedule a task + real task execution**.

Would be great if someone knew if this behavior is expected and could explain how to analyze it.

I'm using Timeline Viewer in dotTrace 2021.3.3.

**UPDATE**

I think I understand the first part of my confusion, namely why **await** time is less than time passed to `Task.Delay` in the `Main` method. This is because the timer of the task started earlier than continuation attached (internal call to`AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted`), therefore it awaits only for the remaining time. In my case this call takes about **300ms** so that `await` time becomes `time passed to Task.Delay - time spent on attaching continuation`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood the way async/await works in dotnet. You can check it in the official Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await

Basically when you execute async code (a method that returns a task) the execution of that method will occur in another thread independent of the original thread, and when you need the result of that task the original thread will wait until the completion of the second thread to retrieve the result. You can read this in their docs:

> The await operator doesn't block the thread that evaluates the async method. When the await operator suspends the enclosing async method, the control returns to the caller of the method.

see this example

```
public async Task<Person> Main()
{
    string name = await GetName(personId);
    int age = await GetAge(personId);
    return new Person(name, age)
}

public async Task<string> GetName(int personId)
{
    //imagine you have a HttpClient in this class that calls an API to get people info
    return _httpClient.GetAsync($"https://someurl.com/getName/{personId}");
}

public async Task<int> GetAge(int personId)
{
    return _httpClient.GetAsync($"https://someurl.com/getAge/{personId}");
}
```

this way the main execution thread will create two other threads to get the info of the age and the name of that personId, and won't stop until the moment this thread needs to retrieve some information of the other two threads (the line which returns a new Person)
So what happens in your code is, as nothing uses the result of that async operation it just continues the original thread without stopping, so it's normal that the async task with the delay lasts longer than the original thread.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but. "the execution of that method will occur in another thread independent of the original thread" - this is not true, the execution of the method will be on the calling thread until `await` is encountered. The **continuation** (the logic after `await`) might be performed on another thread (thread pool's thread)

Comment: this "the original thread will wait until the completion of the second thread to retrieve the result" also seems to be wrong. In async world nothing waits nothing, as soon as the async operation is completed, **the continuation** will be scheduled on a thread pool thread (if it's not completed right away in which case the original calling thread will execute continuation logic).

Comment: Unfortunately the answer says nothing about why `await` time of the `Main` method is less than `800` and why wait time of the `ChildMethod` is greater than `800` and greater than `await` time of `Main` method. Or at least I didn't understand this (if so I'm sorry). Could you please elaborate on where in my code "nothing uses the result of async operation" and what do you mean by "task with the delay lasts longer than the original thread"? How are these related to each other?

Comment: "this way the main execution thread will create two other threads to get the info of the age and the name of that personId" I don't think this is true. `main` thread doesn't create threads, it just executes the `GetName` method which returns a task and then because of `await` the main thread is returned to the caller (not sure what is the caller in Console app), then as soo as the data is ready, continuation (calling `GetAge`) is scheduled on a **thread pool's thread** or a worker thread. A lot of details are missed in my explanation here, but this is the general idea.

Comment: This answer shows serious misunderstandings about asynchronous programming. You're confusing parallel and asynchronous. Parallel means running two parts of your code at the same time, which requires more than one thread. It's about how your code *runs*. Asynchronous means freeing up the current thread when it's waiting on something external (an I/O request, for example). It's about how your code *waits*. When you asynchronously wait, [there is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Comment: "the main thread is returned to the caller (not sure what is the caller in Console app)" - I was wrong about this point, in console app the compiler generates a wrapper method on top of `async Task Main()` which will block the main thread until the task returned by async main is completed (either successfully or not) with the call `Main().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. This is the source https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main

Comment: Okay, sorry for arriving late but this month was a little bit crazy for me, @ E.Shcherbo Isn't it the same? Maybe I'm losing something reading your comment. About the second comment, yes, it awaits, you can read it in the official documentation. @GabrielLuci yep, you are right, sorry for that, if so maybe the user asking the question would appreciate an explanation from you too! And finally to all the people commenting here, remember that comments here later on won't be as noticed as a definitive answer, maybe post more specific answers in the main thread of this post. Have a nice day!